# How composer works?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I haven't any idea about how composer works and add directory  in our folder structure.

Recently I want to add repository to my laravel installation so for that i have used https://github.com/prettus/l5-repository, this repo and as per its installation steps, the first step is to execute following command :

`composer require prettus/l5-repository`

this command creates  prettus directory under vendor so how this works and manage all things?

My questions are:

1. what is the main purpose of composer?
2. what is best structure for that?
3. how it will handle depencdency?
4. what is the `"autoload"` and 'psr-4` and use of both?
5. correct path and structure for namesapcing 'autoload' and 'psr-4'?

Comment: If you aware of apt-get in Debian its the same.. Package manager which is adding all required libs (which must be listed inside packagist or their paths must be added to composer.json), after a package is added composer load its namespace inside composer autoloader and you are able to use it .

Comment: I think this is too much for one question. I like questions that ask how it works but it is really a lot to answer. I would recommend to split it up.

Comment: And read the documentation. https://getcomposer.org/doc And start with a small Composer project https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md. I think you will automatically understand it if you work with it and read the Composer documentation as you go along. Split up your existing PHP project into individual Composer packages. to get full benefit.

Answer (score 6):

*From the Composer documentation:*

> Composer is not a package manager in the same sense as Yum or Apt are. Yes, it deals with "packages" or libraries, but it manages them on a per-project basis, installing them in a directory (e.g. vendor) inside your project. By default it will never install anything globally. Thus, it is a dependency manager.
> ...
> This idea is not new and Composer is strongly inspired by node's npm and ruby's bundler.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#dependency-management

Comment: This answer was copied verbatim from the Composer docs: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#dependency-management I think this should at least be clearly attributed but I am not sure if such an answer is a good idea at all, see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/answers-entirely-copied-though-properly-attributed